# How to automate import API's in azure api management service

Tags: api, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I have created instance in Azure API management service and want to import 200+ APIs. Is there any way to automatically import the APIs in portal by writing script or any other way also want to create a product and group the imported APIs?

Answer (score 1):

You can automate deployment of API's by using [Azure APIM REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/). You will find everything there. Basically whatever you do in Azure Portal on APIM resource by clicking you can do by calling this REST API.

If you don't feel like calling REST API, you can always use [Az.ApiManagement PowerShell Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/?view=azps-6.2.0) or [az apim Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/apim?view=azure-cli-latest) - they have more or less the same functionality.

I guess that is it, the question is too broad to give you more specifics.